# Problem Google consent sdk with multiple activities (admob)

Tags: android, admob

i have a problem  i have implemented google consent sdk correctly in my application
i have show the form correctly for just eu users and displayed the the no-personalized ad for the people who choose it via adding this method

```
  public static void showPersonalizedAds(AdView mAdView,InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd) {

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


}

public static void showNonPersonalizedAds(AdView mAdView,InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd) {


    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("npa", "1");

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
            .build();

    mAdView.loadAd(request);
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(request);
}
```

until now all is well but the problem when i want to go from activity to another
this is what i do before gdpr to switch between activities i'm loading the ad first to prevent invalid clicks

```
   public void goToAct4(View view) {

    final Intent intent = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main4Activity.class);
    if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {

                        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    else {
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

the problem is should i check the form answer every time i switch to another activity  and make a condition (that's a lot of work) and wish method check the status of the consent or what i have to do ?

Comment: did you have to declare mAdView static since you are using it in static method ?

Answer (score 0):

See [Requesting Consent from European Users](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent). It's mandatory to request it once before displaying any ad, because it may set tracking cookies without informed consent. And one also has to provide the possibility to change the settings later on.